# Analize the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(2i)^{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Analyze the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(2i)^{n}}$.

Applying Dirichlet's test with $a_n=\frac{n}{2^n}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{i^n}=(-i)^n$, I can show that the series converges. Using mathematica I know that the series converge to $-\frac{8}{25}-\frac{6}{25}i$. How can I find this number without using mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your series is$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n\text,$$with $z=\frac1{2i}=-\frac i2$. But$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n=z\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}=z\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\right)'=\frac z{(1-z)^2}$$and when $z=-\frac i2$ this is equal to $-\frac8{25}-\frac6{25}i$.

Comment: and also $|z|=1/2<1$